# Positive logarithm in a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: logarithms, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $a \in A_+$ be a positive element. I want to show that $a$ has a positive logarithm if $a$ is invertible.

I just see that the usual $\log$ function is continuous on the spectrum of $a$ since $0 \notin \sigma(a)$ but $\log(a)$ needs not to be positive as this would by functional calculus be true if $\sigma(a) \subset [1,\infty)$, which I do not see.

If $a=e^b$ for some positive $b$, then $\sigma(a) = \{e^t : t \in \sigma(b)\} \subset [1,\infty)$ so $a$ must necessarily have its spectrum in $[1,\infty)$ I guess.

Comment: I'm not convinced that $log(a)$ should be positive, maybe you can conjure up a counterexample?

What happens if you look at the $C^*$-algebra $C([-1,1])$ and consider the element $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}:x\mapsto x+\frac{3}{2}$?

Surely this element is positive, and by the spectral mapping theorem you find that $\sigma(\log(a))=\log([\frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{2}])$.

Comment: The questions is about the existence of some positive logarithm ... This is exercise 3.6 in Conways Book on Operator Theory.

Comment: That is true, so I guess the exercise is just wrong ? See here for reference: https://books.google.de/books?id=nLbpBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=logarithm+of+invertible+element+is+positive&source=bl&ots=acNO0bocRJ&sig=x1ybFmRsNFGX0j6EOZO6Xg9QNmY&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3rorvrdvJAhVItBQKHT4XB2UQ6AEIOzAD#v=onepage&q=logarithm%20of%20invertible%20element%20is%20positive&f=false

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, I doubt Conway's book contains errors in the exercises, but my $C^*$-algebra knowledge is a bit rusty, I guess we're missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the exercise is definitely wrong. Take the C$^*$-algebra $\mathcal A=\mathbb C$, and take $a=1/2$. Then the question is Conway's book claims that there exists a positive element $b$ in $\mathbb C$ such that $e^b=1/2$. Of course, such $b$ does not exist.

Most likely the word "positive" in the question is a typo. In that situation, you can use the continuous functional calculus to obtain the logarithm.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirmation.